# Node JS route is calling res.status(200) in multiple places. How to properly update our function to resolve this issue

Tags: node.js, http

Here is our route in node.js that handle sending a reset-password email to our users.

```
router.post('/forgot-password', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // get email from post body
        const { email = '' } = req.body;

        // find user, return if no user
        const thisUser = await User.findOne({ email: email });
        if (!thisUser) {
            await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000)); // sleep 1 second
            return res.status(200).json({ msg: 'User Does Not Exist' });
        }

        // create reset-password token w/ 1 hour (360,000 milliseconds) expiration, add to user object
        const token = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex');
        const tokenExpires = new Date(Date.now() + 360000);
        const tokenObject = { resetPasswordToken: token, resetPasswordExpires: tokenExpires };
        const userWithToken = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ email: email }, tokenObject);

        // return if error found
        if (!userWithToken) return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'Could not update user with reset-password token' });

        // finally, send the email to the user
        resetPasswordMailer({ email, token })
            .then(() => { // not using "response" param
                console.log(`Success: Reset Password Mailer Emails Both Sent!`);
                return res.status(200).json({ msg: 'Reset password email sent' });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(`Failure: Reset Password Email Failed...`);
                Sentry.captureException(err);
                return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Reset password email failed to send' });
            });

        // and return successful status
        return res.status(200).json({ msg: 'Password reset request received' });
    } catch (err) {
        Sentry.captureException(err);
        return res.status(500).json({ statusCode: 500, message: err.message });
    }
});
```

We are receiving the error message `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`, I believe this is happening because our `res.status()` is getting called in multiple places on individual function calls. It seems that the final `return res.status(200).json({ msg: 'Password reset request received' });` gets called, and then also in the Mailer.then(), that `return res.status(200).json({ msg: 'Reset password email sent' });` then gets called after the email is sent.

How should we update this route? If we remove the `return res.status(200).json({ msg: 'Password reset request received' });`, then ESList throws a warning `expected to return a value at the end of async arrow function`

Comment: Why are you using `.then` in an async function? The control flow might be clearer if you handled promises consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a dumb/easy question in hindsight. I've replaced the .then() and .catch() with:

```
// handle emailer (replacing .then(), .catch() with await in a try/catch)
try {
    await resetPasswordMailer({ email, token });
    console.log(`Success: Reset Password Mailer Emails Both Sent!`);
    return res.status(200).json({ msg: 'Reset password email sent' });
} catch (mailerErr) {
    console.log(`Failure: Reset Password Email Failed...`);
    Sentry.captureException(mailerErr);
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Reset password email failed to send' });
}
```